# Import database with password Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have an admin table with : id, name, surname, email and password fields... 
I have to import into a Laravel database those information from another database where the passwords are not hashed.

If i'd like to import datas i should write :

```
INSERT INTO admins (name, surname, email, password)
VALUES (myName, mySurname, myEmail, myPassword);
```

I wonder how i can Hash the password values ? 
Is there a mysql "methop" which allow it ? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply used another laravel install where i installed iseed

```
composer require orangehill/iseed
```

then i imported my database into a database and then created a seeder from an existing table

```
php artisan iseed admins
```

Then 
    php artisan make:seeder AdminsTableSeeder

From then i just made a find and replace ...

```
'password' => 'mypassword',
```

is replaced by :

```
'password' => bcrypt('mypassword'),
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has a helper method to hash:

```
bcrypt('password')

DB::insert('insert into admins (name, surname, email, password) values (?, ?, ?,?)', [$myName, $mySurname, $myEmail, bcrypt($myPassword)]);
```

As well as a facade, `Hash`

```
Hash::make('password')

DB::insert('insert into admins (name, surname, email, password) values (?, ?, ?,?)', [$myName, $mySurname, $myEmail, Hash::make($myPassword)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a php scrypt. That handles the hashing for you.

You could bcrypt the password and then put it in your query.

But since you are using laravel what you could do is make a seeder

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/seeding

Then with hashing

https://laravel.com/docs/master/hashing

should give you a headstart

Comment: I found out a solution thanks to your comment ! I used iseed and i solved my problem